# Asynchronous DispatchQueue in loop

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

> So my goal here is to basically perform a query in a while loop and append results of the query to my array. When I run the code my "level" variable starts from zero and increments infinitely. I'm highly convinced that my problem is caused by fact that my code is running on 2 async queues but just can't figure out the exact cause.

func displayPathOf(argument: Argument, threadTableView: UITableView)  {

```
    array.removeAll()
    threadTableView.reloadData()
    var level = argument.level!-1
    array.insert(argument, at: 0)
    var stop = false

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {

        repeat {

            level += 1
            print(level)
            let query = Argument.query()?.whereKey("level", equalTo: level).addDescendingOrder("reach")
            query?.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (object, error) in

                if object != nil {

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        array.append(object as! Argument)
                        print(array)
                        threadTableView.reloadData()}

                } else {

                    stop = true
                    print(error)

                }
            })
         } while stop == false
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem ?  Is it running on an infinite loop ?

Comment: correct.. this is what i see in the console as a result of print(level) portion of my code: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, .....

Answer (score 0):

Your code boils down to:

```
do-in-background {
    repeat {
        level += 1
        do-in-background { ... }
    } while stop == false
}
```

`do-in-background` (i.e. both `async` and `getFirstObjectInBackground`) returns immediately, so from the point of view of this loop, it doesn't matter what's in the block. This is equivalent to a tight loop incrementing level as fast as it can.

It looks like you're trying to serialize your calls to `getFirstObjectInBackground`. You can do that one of two ways:

- Have your completion block kick off the next search itself and remove the `repeat` loop.
- Use a `DispatchGroup` to wait until the completion block is done.

In your case, I'd probably recommend the first. Get rid of `stop` and make a function something (vaguely) like:

```
func fetchObject(at level: Int) {
    let query = Argument.query()?.whereKey("level", equalTo: level).addDescendingOrder("reach")
    query?.getFirstObjectInBackground(block: { (object, error) in
        if let object = object {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            array.append(object as! Argument)
            print(array)
            threadTableView.reloadData()}

            // Schedule the next loop
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async { fetchObject(level + 1) }

         } else {
            print(error)
        }
    })
}
```